# Will Mercurial automatically convert $Id$ to what Subversion does?

Tags: mercurial

I am wondering if Mercurial by default converts $Id$ to the equivalent of Subversion which is something like this: test.php 110 2009-04-28 05:20:41Z dordal $. Does anyone know?

Comment: Using keyword conversion with a DVCS is a really bad idea.  It's a good idea with svn and cvs because it's possible for different files in your repo to be updated to different revisions, but in Mercurial or git all files are at the same point, so you can just use `hg id` to get that value or in a build script use something like `$(hg id --id)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No, it won't, but you can enable it.**

https://web.archive.org/web/20121007024058/
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/KeywordPlan

> **Why You Don't Need It**
>
> Keyword expansion is not supported in the core of Mercurial because it's of limited utility in a modern system and it's problematic from performance and binary integrity standpoints. For most human uses, one can simply ask the revision control system. And for situations where the revision control system is not available, the tag is very likely to be incorrect!
>
> One common use that remains is automatically integrating version information into a software build. This is pretty easily accomplished without keyword substitution by doing something like the following in your Makefile:
>
> ...
>
> **Basic Emulation**
>
> If that's not enough for you, it is possible to emulate this behavior with an extension.
>
> ...
>
> An example extension that provides $Author$ and $Date$ keywords is attached (keyword.py)
>
> See also [KeywordExtension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/KeywordExtension).

---

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/KeywordExtension

> **Keyword Extension**
>
> This extension is distributed with Mercurial
>
> Overview
>
> This extension allows the expansion of RCS/CVS-like and user defined keys in text files tracked by Mercurial. Expansion takes place in the working directory or/and when creating a distribution using "hg archive".
>
> Keywords expand to the changeset data pertaining to the latest change relative to the working directory parent of each file.
>
> *If you just want to version your entire repo, do not use this extension but let your build system take care of it. Something along the lines of ...*
>
> ,,,
>
> ***For speed and security reasons (avoidance of inadvertently expanded keywords) it is recommended to enable the extension per repo only in repo/.hg/hgrc, not globally, and to fine tune the [keyword] filename patterns with great care.***

Comment: Thanks, I should have tried to search better that pretty much answers my question.

Comment: @Darren - Glad to help.  I wanted to make sure you got the whole story on keyword expansion (the Mercurial way is to not do it, or else, just enable as little of it as possible).  I also know it can be tough to figure out the exact term to search for in an unfamiliar software package ("keyword substitution"?, "id replacement"? "keyword expansion"?), especially when one of the terms is as general as "keyword" or "id".

Comment: I understand now why not to do it, so there is a chance I won't and I am pretty sure it has to deal with the way versioning works with Mercurial as well as Git as to why its a bad idea, particularly because of local repositories as well as remote.

Answer (score 1):

You have a similar feature with [Keyword Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/KeywordExtension) (distributed with Mercurial)

> This extension allows the expansion of RCS/CVS-like and user defined keys in text files tracked by Mercurial. Expansion takes place in the working directory or/and when creating a distribution using "`hg archive`".
>
> Keywords expand to the changeset data pertaining to the latest change relative to the working directory parent of each file.

For instance:

```
Id = {file|basename},v {node|short} {date|utcdate} {author|user}
```

would be expanded as:

```
$Id: demo.txt,v 2ad3dcb8d811 2007/07/17 12:00:47 blacktrash $
```

Note:

> For speed and security reasons (avoidance of inadvertently expanded keywords) it is recommended:
>
> - to enable the extension per repo only in `repo/.hg/hgrc`, not globally,
> - and to fine tune the `[keyword]` filename patterns with great care.